# How to write a number pattern generator program in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logic

I have to make a pattern like this:

```
=========1=========
=======22122=======
====33322122333====
4444333221223334444
```

I have not found the logic yet. I tried to code it, but the output is different.

Here is the output of my working code snippet:

```
----1-----
---123----
--12345---
-1234567--
123456789-
```

```js
function nomor3(input){
    let temp = '';
    for (let x = 1; x <= input; x++){
        for (let y = input ; y > x; y--){
            temp += "-";
        }        
    
        for (let z = 1; z <= (x * 2) - 1; z++){
                temp += z;
        }
        for (let k = input; k >= x; k--){
            temp += "-";
        }

        temp += '\n';
    }
    
    return temp
}

console.log(nomor3(5));
```

Comment: Please add expected pattern as text

Answer (score 0):

The logic for each level - say 4th level - it begins with the digit of the level to the count of the digit, then one less and so on. So line 4 looks like 4444-333-22-1 and backwards (dashes added for demonstration).

So here we build each line like that, starting from the biggest so we know its length so we can center other lines with dashes. We use arrays here and reversing them because it's easier than strings. But lastly we `join` so we have a string.

```js
function pyramide(level) {
  var len = null;
  var result = [];
  while (level > 0) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = level; i > 1; i--) {
      for (var repeat = 0; repeat < i; repeat++) {
        arr.push(i)
      }
    }
    var str_level = arr.join("") + "1" + arr.reverse().join("");
    if (len === null) {
      len = str_level.length;
    }
    while (str_level.length < len) {
      str_level = "-" + str_level + "-";
    }
    result.push(str_level);
    level--;
  }
  return result.reverse().join("\n");
}


console.log(pyramide(5))
```